# Extend buttons to show long messages

Tags: node.js, botframework

### Preface

I am currently coding Microsoft's Botbuilder SDK in Node.js.

### The Problem

In the case of prompting the user to choose from a set of options that are clickable buttons, the text of the buttons get cut off with appended ellipses. Here is an example using Microsoft's Bot Framework Emulator:

[image: Screenshot of Button Prompt with Long Text]

Here is the code:

```
bot.dialog('mainMenu', [
    (session, args, next) => {
        // buttonOptions is an array of size 4 all with the
        //     string 'VERY LONG TEXT THAT GETS CUT OFF'
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'What would you like to do?'
        , buttonOptions, { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button });
    }
]);
```

### The Desired Result

I would like to show the entire text of the buttons. I am aware that the listStyle: list exists that shows the entire text, but I am looking for a solution that allows button-use.

### The Question

Is there a way to expand the buttons to show the entire length of long text in these types of prompts? Alternative perspectives not confined to this listStyle are welcome.

Comment: How they are being rendered will depend on the channels, if your bot are using in WebChat, then it is possible to change the style of buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the choices are displayed is implemented by each channel, so you may concentrate on your target channel.

Some channels implementations (typically emulator and webchat) are open-source and you can create your own fork to build the behavior you need.

### Emulator

Bot Framework's emulator sources are located on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/master/src/client/).

### Webchat

I already replied to a similar question about customizing the webchat to display all the text of the buttons. To avoid duplicates, please have a look directly here: [Using botbuilder SDK's Prompt.choice(), is it possible to have a custom tooltip which displays long choice-text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018290/using-botbuilder-sdks-prompt-choice-is-it-possible-to-have-a-custom-tooltip/48021311#48021311)

It allow rendering buttons multiline like that:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMT4d.png]

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the text "\n". So the button look it similar like this
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN8t5.png)

For a better result, I determined a maximum value and divided the string length. With this number I made a split. After I searched the last white space to put "\n".