# Deploy customize webchat bot framework

Tags: botframework, bots, web-chat

I clone this repo https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat and I managed to edit css in local.
I would like to know what I need to deploy to use webchat online ?

Thanks you for you help

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#easy-in-your-non-react-website-run-web-chat-inline

Answer (score 4):

> I clone this repo https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat and I managed to edit css in local. I would like to know what I need to deploy to use webchat online?

After you [customize&build your own web chat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#building-web-chat), to embed web chat in your website, you should include your built `botchat.css` and `botchat.js` file in your project and reference `botchat.css` and `botchat.js` in your web page.

> I want to add a widget like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD7i4.png) to open my chatbot, what I need to do?

It seems that you’d like to display the chat icon in your web page to allow user dynamically open/collapse your web chat, to achieve the requirement, you need not to modify the `botchat.js` file, the following code sample work for me , you can refer to it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="BotChat/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="BotChat/botchat.js"></script>
    <style>
        #mychat {
            margin: 10px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 30px;
            right: 10px;
            z-index: 1000000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <!--other page contents-->
        <img id="mychat" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD7i4.png" style="float:right" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    (function () {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
        div.outerHTML = "<div id='botDiv' style='width: 400px; height: 0px; margin:10px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; right:0; z-index: 1000;><div  id='botTitleBar' style='height: 40px; width: 400px; position:fixed; cursor: pointer;'></div></div>";
        BotChat.App({
            directLine: { secret: '{directline_secret}' },
            user: { id: 'You' },
            bot: { id: '{your_botid}' }
        }, document.getElementById("botDiv"));

        document.getElementsByClassName("wc-header")[0].setAttribute("id", "chatbotheader");
        document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.target.matches = e.target.matches || e.target.msMatchesSelector;
            if (e.target.matches('#chatbotheader')) {
                var botDiv = document.querySelector('#botDiv');

                botDiv.style.height = "0px";

                document.getElementById("mychat").style.display = "block";
            };
        });

        document.getElementById("mychat").addEventListener("click", function (e) {

            document.getElementById("botDiv").style.height = '500px';

            e.target.style.display = "none";
        })
    }());
</script>
```

*Test result:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I want to add a widget like this 
[image]
to open my chatbot, what I need to do ? Is it enough to modify the botchat.js file ?

How to have an application like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018290/using-botbuilder-sdks-prompt-choice-is-it-possible-to-have-a-custom-tooltip)?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use iframe then you can't customize the design . for customize design you need to use Direct line by you can change design as well as make bot fully responsive.

Here is the code i am using working fine for me:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js lang-en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title></title>
  <!-- For Bot Frame -->
  <link href="../assets/SCSS/botchat-fullwindow.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../assets/SCSS/botchat.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="personal-body">

  <!-- For Bot Code -->
  <div id="BotChatElement">
  </div>
  <img src="../assets/images/chat-2-icon.png" onclick="openchatbot()" class="open-bot" id="button_chat" />

  <script src="../assets/JS/botchat.js"></script>
  <script>

    var model = {
      "userId": "demo1234",
      "userName": "You",
      "botId": "Chatbot Main Tree",
      "botIconUrl": "",
      "botName": "Chatbot Main Tree",
      "secret": "",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "directLineUrl": "https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline",
      "webSocketEnabled": "false"
    };[enter image description here][1]

    BotChat.App({
      directLine: {
        secret: model.secret,
        token: model.token,
        domain: model.directLineUrl,
        webSocket: false,
        sendTyping: true
      },
      user: { id: model.userId, name: model.userName },
      bot: { id: model.botId, name: model.botName },
      sendTyping: true,
      resize: 'window'
    },
      document.getElementById("BotChatElement"));

    function openchatbot() {
      $(".wc-chatview-panel *").removeClass("maximizebot");
      $(".wc-chatview-panel").css({ 'bottom': '0', 'display': 'block' });

    }

    $(".minimize-icon").on('click',
      function () {
        $(".wc-chatview-panel").removeClass("minimize-icon");
        $(".wc-chatview-panel ").toggleClass("minimizebot");
        $(".minimize-icon ").toggleClass("maximizebot");

      });
    $(".close-icon").on('click',
      function () {
        $(".wc-chatview-panel ").removeClass("minimizebot");
        $(".wc-chatview-panel ").removeClass("maximizebot");
        $(".wc-chatview-panel").css({ 'bottom': '-500px', 'display': 'none' });
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it does not work, the bot is displayed on the whole page

Comment: yes you need to customize the CSC file for custom design

Answer (score 0):

### **To deploy your bot follow those steps:**

1. Create an Azure account.

   > You can create free trial Azure subscription from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/).
2. Deploying the a MS Bot framework code to Azure:

   > - You can see this [video](https://youtu.be/n3oXcqOKPuw) deploying a MS Bot framework code to Azure
   >     WebChat channel using Visual Studio.
   > - Also you can check this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-deploy-a-bot-to-azure-using-visual-studio-2017/).  (However, this tutorial use old version of Azure portal).
3. After connecting the bot with WebChat channel, you can use the `Embed code` in your HTML code.